# How to get same value for current time in milliseconds on localhost and server?

Tags: ntp, scheduledexecutorservice, system-administration, weblistener

I have created a web listener which contains a *ScheduledExecutorService* to run a job on a specific date and time and after that at regular fixed time interval. This scheduler checks for a specific date and time to do the job. The scheduler works with UTC time.

The problem is when I run it on my localhost it works perfectly but when I put it on remote server (server and my localhost are not in same TimeZone) it fails to work properly( they produce different value of *System.currentTimeMillis()* . With the help of a logger I have checked  the value of *System.currentTimeMillis()* both on localhost and server and they are different.

Here is my Scheduler.

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, namedThreadFactory);
final Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
        public void run() {

                    logger.info("Scheduler ran");

                    try {


                        if (date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1) {
                            if (!(System.currentTimeMillis() - getStartTime().getTime() > 300000)) {
                                logger.info("Doing the job");
                                myJob();
                            }
                            else{
                                logger.info("Too late after scheduled time");
                            }
                        } else {

                            logger.info("Current Day of Month: " + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ". Job will be done on  1st Day of the month");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                        logger.info(ex);
                    }

                }

            }, getInitialDelay(), (2*60000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

        private static long getOffsetTime() {
            Calendar dateForOffset = new GregorianCalendar();
            dateForOffset.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            int days = dateForOffset.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            switch (days) {
                case 31:
                    offsetTimeInMilli = PERIOD;
                    break;
                case 29:
                    offsetTimeInMilli = (-1) * PERIOD;
                    break;
                case 28:
                    offsetTimeInMilli = (-2) * PERIOD;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return offsetTimeInMilli;
        }

        private static long getInitialDelay() {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.info( "Current Time " + currentTime);
            logger.info("Set Time to do the job   -->" + getStartTime().getTime() + " Milliseconds");
            initialDelay = getStartTime().getTime() - currentTime;
            logger.info("Initial Delay Found : " + initialDelay + " Milliseconds");
            return initialDelay;

        }

        private static Date getStartTime() {
            Calendar d10am = Calendar.getInstance();
            d10am.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            //logger.info("Day of Month  ----- >" + d10am.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            //d10am.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            d10am.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
            d10am.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
            d10am.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            d10am.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            d10am.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            //logger.info("Day of Month  ----- >" + Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return d10am.getTime();
        }
```

Comment: but what does this mean: ***it fails to work properly***, how can we help you with such a broad description of the error?

Comment: I have edited the question. The main problem is the scheduler gives different value of System.currentTimeMillis() that causes unexpected results.

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() returns the time of the computer where the JVM is running. Why do you want the same values in both the servers. Whats your actual problem.

Comment: What are the values of currentTimeMilli's? my bets this is a matter of a few seconds.

Comment: Time on my localhost is 1499150478841 and on server is 1499168889585

Comment: Avinash I have to decide an if condition to complete the job which is  based on time which must be same on both systems.

Comment: Are those two millisecond values taken at the same time?

Comment: not exactly as I had to run both server manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or both of them must be wrong.  The value `System.currentTimeMillis()` is independent of time zones.  Really, the proper way to synchronize times on these servers is for each server to synchronize with a time server using NTP (Network Time Protocol).

This is more of a systems administration problem than a Java programming problem.

Comment: Thanks, it really was a system administration problem. All I had to do was install ntp on my system and sync with a time server using "ntpdate time.apple.com".